# How to bring Combo Box inside TableView in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, combobox, javafx-2

Please help me with simple code to bring combo box inside a table view .

```
column2.setCellValueFactory(new ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(null));
column2.setPrefWidth(150);
```

Is this the way to add combo box into table view.Is there need to create fxml for create table view.Please if you have runnable code please share

Comment: something like this would work:   `column2.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn("A","B", "C")); `

Comment: tnq @Kachna it works

Answer (score 1):

column2.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn("A","B", "C"));